# Is Lector the Exceed alive?

Tags: fairy-tail

Sting the dragon slayer has Lector, the Exceed cat.

Is Lector alive or dead? Did Minerva lie to Sting by saying she transported Lector to a different place or is it true?

Comment: just keep watching/reading. You'll know soon

Comment: you will spoil yourself by asking for these things, just watch and enjoy the curiosity

Answer (score 1):

Well, he's alive, he was saved by Minerva's Magic seconds before being killed. From manga chapter 307, The Order Of The Hungry Wolves

[image: manga chp 307]

And she's not lying

[image: manga chp 322]